# Having a list with a script and getting the gameobject from it

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a script that has a list with the type being a certain script. Then wanting to instantiate all of the members of this list (GameObjects have this script). I've tried doing a for loop over the list and then doing `.GetComponent<GameObject>();` but of course that doesn't work for obvious reasons. So Is there a way to do this?

For anyone wondering why I'm trying to do this, I want to limit anyone else that is using this script to only add gameobjects with this script (since I don't want gameobject without this script being spawned)

Maybe having a reference on the certain script that knows what gameobject has been attached to it? or is there a better way to do this

Thank you :)

Comment: How are you adding instances of the script to your list?  Can you add the code that shows what you're currently doing?

Comment: Also when you say 'GameObjects have this script' - which script? The script that has the list or the script that is the type for the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier if you added your code to the question.

---

Well, [`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) is obviously not of type [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) ([`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) inherits from `Component`).

It sounds like what you have is a `List<SomeComponent>`.

So you can simply access the property [`Component.gameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html) which is the reference to the `GameObject` that component is attached to.

```
List<SomeComponent> list;

...

foreach(var component in list)
{
    var obj = component.gameObject;

    ...
}
```

---

Note however that you actually don't need this. It sounds like you want to pass the elements of the list to [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) which also takes a `Component` (or better said any `Object` the mother class of `GameObject`, `Component` and `ScriptableObject`) as prefab parameter. It then returns the same type of the given prefab.